# Проблема с вёрсткой с Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В макете имеется полоска (синяя сверху), которая вылезает за край сетки (контейнера).
Если она была бы с обеих сторон, то проблем нет - делаю фоном вне контейнера, а контент в контейнере (как сделаны другие блоки), но тут вопрос в том, что полоска вылезает за сетку только с одной стороны и в голову ничего не приходит, как это реализовать.

[image: макет]

Comment: ставьте `container-fluid` для фона, который должен быть на всю ширину

Comment: Фон должен быть не на всю ширину. Для наглядности прикрепил кусок макета. Наверху синяя полоска, занимает 10 колонок, но она должна "уходить" за край сетки с одной стороны.

Comment: тогда можно попробовать `position: absolute` для этой "синей линии" (либо вариации с псевдоэлементом для неё и т.п.) и растянуть её вправо до нужного размера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Фон выглядывает из-под контейнера только с одной стороны

Градиент позволяет задать фон с синей полосой, идущей от середины до правого края экрана:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, darkblue 50%);
background-size: 100% 30px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Чтобы этот фон оказался под основным контейнером, можно сделать матрёшку:

> `.container-fluid` > `.row` с градиентом > `.container` > `.row` с шапкой сайта

Или:

> `<header>` с градиентом > `.container` > `.row` с шапкой сайта

Для наглядности подкрасил области с логотипом и меню в разные оттенки синего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### 1. .container-fluid

В бутстрапе [два варианта контейнера](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container): `container-fluid` всегда занимает всю ширину экрана, а просто `container` задаёт колонку фиксированной ширины.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/ohLhdwqw

```css
.header {
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, darkblue 50%);
    background-size: 100% 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
.contacts {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.logo {
  background: #ccf;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.menu {
  background: #99f;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 logo">Logo</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 contacts">Contacts</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 menu">Menu</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### 2. <header>

В HTML5 элемент `<header>` задаёт [шапку сайта или раздела](https://webref.ru/html/header).

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/g54am6u4

```css
header {
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, darkblue 50%);
    background-size: 100% 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
.contacts {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.logo {
  background: #ccf;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.menu {
  background: #99f;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 logo">Logo</div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 contacts">Contacts</div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 menu">Menu</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо! С .container-fluid пока не разбирался, по-этому не очень понимаю, как его использовать.

Comment: @VeroLom В бутстрапе [два варианта контейнера](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid). `container-fluid` всегда занимает всю ширину экрана, а просто `container`задаёт материала страницы колонку фиксированной ширины. Если нужна аккуратная колонка для меню, текста и фотографий. то берём `container`. Если нужно занять всю ширину экрана - `container-fluid`.

Comment: Как я понял, если у части страницы (блока) будет фон, отличающийся от остальных блоков, то надо сначала прописать `.container-fluid`, в нём элемент с фоном, а в нём уже обычный `.container` с контентом?
Бутстрап только недавно начал учить, ещё не всё знаю и осмыслил.

Comment: @VeroLom `.container` задаёт общую колонку для материала, а  `.container-fluid` помогает добавить блок, выходящий за пределы этой колонки. Например, фотографию, слайдшоу или видео. Кстати, чтобы задать фон на всю ширину экрана, можно использовать не только  `.container-fluid`, но и `<header>`. Добавил этот вариант в свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если в контейрере синяя синяя полоса занимает больше половины, то можно сделать так:

http://www.bootply.com/bdhIp9EVor

```
<style>
#header:after {
    content: "fill";
    width: 50%;
    background: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:-999;
}
#menu {
    background: lightblue; 
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container" id="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">LOGO</div>
            <div class="col-md-8" id="menu">NAV</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```